# What's up with some typescript 3.7 features not being available if you target ESNext?

Tags: typescript

I'm using bigint literals in my angular project, only available in ESNext, but for some reason the null-coalescing operator discussed [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing) appears not to be available when targeting ESNext.

```
   this._id = id ?? Util.makeGuid()
```

is giving error `TS1109 : Expression expected` in the compile stage with a little red squigly under the second question mark.

I don't understand why that is.  I thought ESNext was supposed to be targting the latest javascript version, so why are these new features not available?

By way of example, try this code in [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/), which works fine when set to V3.7.2 and target ES2017.

```
class Foo {
    name: string;
    constructor(name?: string) {
        this.name = name ?? "I am Foo";
    }
}

let f = new Foo();
alert(f.name);
```

But if the "Config" tab is used to set target to ESNext, the code fails with a syntax error in the console.

My Chrome version is:

```
Google Chrome is up to date
Version 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

Here are some pictures for the doubters:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I thought ESNext was supposed to be targting the latest javascript version, so why are these new features not available?

The error `TS1109` means the version of the compiler used didn't understand the TS code because it is not a part of TS syntax supported by this version. So it rejected the TS code as invalid and didn't come to the point of deciding which JS version should be used to generate the transpiled code.

> targeting ESNext

The `--module` compiler option affects the output JS code generated by a compiler that "was happy" with TS code and decided to transpile. More precisely it [affects](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) the module code generation.

To get support for the nullish coalescing operator install TypeScript version 3.7.x. Then ensure Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code actually uses this version for your project. For example, if you use VS Code follow the steps described
[here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling#_using-newer-typescript-versions).

**P.S.**
After you supplied the `class Foo` code which looks fine and mentioned the playground, I checked it. As expected, when the compiler is set to 3.6.3 it triggers a syntax error and this happens:

> a little red squigly under the second question mark.

If the compiler is set to 3.7.2, the code compiles and runs without problems when  the Module under Config menu is set to any setting including ESNext.

> demonstrates this problem in TypeScript playground when version is set to 3.72 and target is set to ESNext

Cannot reproduce it using currently the latest Chrome 79.0.3945.13. It suggests a playground compatibility issue with your browser. The playground's browser compatibility has its limits.

**P.P.S.**

> Try setting not the module setting but the target setting to ESNext

This will not affect how the compiler treats TS code so with Target=ESNext the nullish coalescing operator is still accepted when the version is set to 3.7.2 and rejected when the version is set to 3.6.3. When accepted the compiler happily transpiles TS into JS code but attempt to run it triggers a run-time error (visible in Console only) because no browser has a JS engine capable of running ESNext.

Comment: Alas, that is not the problem.  I have revised the question above that demonstrates this problem in TypeScript playground when version is set to 3.72 and target is set to ESNext.

Comment: Try setting not the module setting but the target setting to ESNext.

Comment: Um, I swear to god I'm not making this up WinWiz1, See above for the pictures.  Did you actually try this, or are you just asserting it?

Comment: I tried in all cases. The _Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'_ occurs at __run-time__ and is exactly the same error I referred to earlier when I said: _the compiler happily transpiles TS into JS code but attempt to run it triggers a run-time error (visible in Console only) because no browser has a JS engine capable of running ESNext._ This error is different from the __transpile time__ error you initially referred to and described as _a little red squigly under the second question mark_.

Comment: What you said was "if the compiler is set to 3.7.2., the code compiles and runs without problems, even after I pointed out that it doesnt' work with target set to ESNext.  If you are suggesting that its is the expected behavior that there is no browser capable of running targeting ESNext, then what is the point of having the setting available in the first place on TypeScript playground (or anywher else).  This whole thread is a bit of a distraction and doesn't really answer the question.